# C++ Read file line by line then split each line using the delimiter

Tags: c++, readfile

I want to read a txt file line by line and after reading each line, I want to split the line according to the tab "\t" and add each part to an element in a struct.

my struct is 1*char and 2*int

```
struct myStruct
{
    char chr;
    int v1;
    int v2;
}
```

where chr can contain more than one character.

A line should be something like:

```
randomstring TAB number TAB number NL
```

Comment: a char cannot contain more than one character, you probably mean char*
also the purpose of v1 and 2 is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @Mark he's probably bussy editing...

Comment: Any code you can show us? Can you tell us what `v1` and `v2` are? Are there are constraints?

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff: I want to read the file line by line. When I read the first line, I want to split it using the tab as a delimiter then each part of the line is set to a variable in the struct. Next move to next line till eof.

Comment: @sikas so a line should be something like : randomstring TAB number TAB number NL ?

Comment: @flownt: yes, that is the format of each line in the file. So how can I read each line, split and add to struct?

Comment: @sikas: Okay, you have the pseudocode all worked out.  So what's stopping you from translating it to C++?

Comment: @Mark: I have the pseudocode, yes. But can`t apply!! I haven`t written any code in C++ for nearly 2 yrs so I kinda forgot all about it :S ...

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @sikas Then now would be a great time to re-learn C++. Otherwise, are you just expecting someone here to do all the work for you?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:
Note: if chr can contain more than 1 character then use a string to represent it.

```
std::ifstream file("plop");
std::string   line;

while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream   linestream(line);
    std::string         data;
    int                 val1;
    int                 val2;

    // If you have truly tab delimited data use getline() with third parameter.
    // If your data is just white space separated data
    // then the operator >> will do (it reads a space separated word into a string).
    std::getline(linestream, data, '\t');  // read up-to the first tab (discard tab).

    // Read the integers using the operator >>
    linestream >> val1 >> val2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you intend to use this struct for C as well, I would replace the intended char* with std::string.

Next, as I intend to be able to read it from a stream I would write the following function:

```
std::istream & operator>>( std::istream & is, myStruct & my )
{
    if( std::getline(is, my.str, '\t') )
       return is >> my.v1 >> my.v2;
}
```

with str as the std::string member. This writes into your struct, using tab as the first delimiter and then any white-space delimiter will do before the next two integers. (You can force it to use tab).

To read line by line you can either continue reading these, or read the line first into a string then put the string into an istringstream and call the above.

You will need to decide how to handle failed reads. Any failed read above would leave the stream in a failed state.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::ifstream in("fname");
while(in){
    std::string line;
    std::getline(in,line);
    size_t lasttab=line.find_last_of('\t');
    size_t firsttab=line.find_last_of('\t',lasttab-1);
    mystruct data;
    data.chr=line.substr(0,firsttab).c_str();
    data.v1=atoi(line.substr(firsttab,lasttab).c_str());
    data.v2=atoi(line.substr(lasttab).c_str());
}
```

Comment: Please lookup why not to use in as the condition of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had some difficulty following some of the suggestions here, so I'm posting a complete example of overloading both input and output operators for a struct over a tab-delimited file. As a bonus, it also takes the input either from `stdin` or from a file supplied via the command arguments.

I believe this is about as simple as it gets while adhering to the semantics of the operators.

---

**pairwise.h**

```
#ifndef PAIRWISE_VALUE
#define PAIRWISE_VALUE

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct PairwiseValue
{
    std::string labelA;
    std::string labelB;
    float value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PairwiseValue& p);

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, PairwiseValue& p);

#endif
```

---

**pairwise.cc**

```
#include "pairwise.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PairwiseValue& p)
{
    os << p.labelA << '\t' << p.labelB << '\t' << p.value << std::endl;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, PairwiseValue& p)
{
    PairwiseValue pv;

    if ((is >> pv.labelA >> pv.labelB >> pv.value))
    {
        p = pv;
    }

    return is;
}
```

---

**test.cc**

```
#include <fstream>
#include "pairwise.h"

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); // disable synch with stdio (enables input buffering)

    std::string ifilename;
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        ifilename = argv[1];
    }

    const bool use_stdin = ifilename.empty();
    std::ifstream ifs;
    if (!use_stdin)
    {
        ifs.open(ifilename);

        if (!ifs)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error opening input file: " << ifilename << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    std::istream& is = ifs.is_open() ? static_cast<std::istream&>(ifs) : std::cin;

    PairwiseValue pv;

    while (is >> pv)
    {
        std::cout << pv;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Compiling**

```
g++ -c pairwise.cc test.cc
g++ -o test pairwise.o test.o
```

**Usage**

```
./test myvector.tsv
cat myvector.tsv | ./test
```