# Cannot find the end of an array when opening a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

So I want to open a file and display the contents. Thing is, I don't know how many elements are used and how many elements are empty. So, when I try to display the elements the first few are shown but the rest are random numbers. How do I find and display the exact number of elements?

file:

```
10011   Ali         Doha        12355555    11-5-14     3434    7890 
10015   Ahmed       Al-Khor     51244444    13-6-14     3425    4455 
10014   Mohammed    Al-Wakra    53344333    17-7-14     5566    1234 
10012   Omar        Doha        56666666    10-8-14     1234    5678 
10013   Youssef     Al-Khor     7555512     5-5-14      88000   4532 
10019   Hamad       Al-Wakra    81234567    8-6-14      3125    1265     
10018   Jassim      Doha        86753541    9-7-14      9875    5566
```

code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    const int isize=10;
    ifstream datafile;
    datafile.open("D:\customers.txt");
    int customer_number[isize];
    string customer_name[isize]; 
    string customer_address[isize]; 
    long contact[isize]; 
    string Due_date[isize]; 
    int water_consumption[isize]; 
    int electricity_consumption[isize];
    double total_bill[isize];
    if (!datafile)//to know if the file is exist or not
         cout << "error" << endl;
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            datafile >> customer_number[i];
            datafile>> customer_name[i];
            datafile>> customer_address[i];
            datafile>> contact[i];
            datafile>> Due_date[i];
            datafile>> water_consumption[i];
            datafile>> electricity_consumption[i];}
    }

        for(int i=0; i<isize; i++)
        {
              if(customer_number[i] == '\0')
                      break;
          else
                  cout << customer_number[i] << "\t" << customer_name[i] << "\t" << customer_address[i] << "\t" << contact[i] << "\t"
                      << Due_date[i] << "\t" << water_consumption[i] << "\t" << electricity_consumption[i] << "\t" <<  endl;

   }
      datafile.close();
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I can't understand what do you want, can you please tell me what are you trying to do? What is empty and what are you trying to display...

Comment: see here's the thing, each array is 1000 elements long, but only 7 are used, how do I find out they're 7?

Comment: Each array is 1000 elements? Not in the posted code. They're all `const int isize=10;` dimensioned. Anything more than 10 iterations and you're blowing out your array. Not that you'd know it since you never check any boundaries nor any IO operations.

Comment: You have three options here. 1) add a number in the beginning telling you the number of preceding elements in the array. 2) add the each array element in a separate line. 3) make a separator, I mean assume that a character like `$` is the separator between each array elements and that char can't be used as a normal char

Comment: After the post modification, I saw the file better. You can easily read line by line and then split on space, or tab?

Comment: @user3684811 refer to this post, I think this is what you want >> [C++ Read file line by line then split each line using the delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910326/c-read-file-line-by-line-then-split-each-line-using-the-delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each text line is a record, thus use `std::getline` with `std::string` to read a record.

When the number of records is unknown, you need a dynamic container, such as `std::vector`, `std::list` or `std::map`, not a fixed size array.

You will need to research the `std::string` methods and also `std::istringstream` for *parsing* the text line into native format fields.  There are lots of examples on StackOverflow on how to do this.

So stop using fixed size arrays and use `std::vector` instead.